# How to toggle worker dynos on/off using Heroku CLI

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have this dynos in my Heroku application :
`worker: node app.js`

How do I turn it off / on using the Heroku CLI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found it.

`$ heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a my-application` to start it
`$ heroku ps:scale worker=0 -a my-application` to stop it